# How do I add only a subset of new endorsed skills to my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

When somebody has been endorsed for skills beyond what they put on their own LinkedIn profile, LinkedIn presents them with a list of these skills at the top of the profile, along with thumbnails of the people who endorsed those skills, and encourages the profile holder to click a button and add all those skills to the profile.  Sometimes, these endorsements are accurate in that the profile holder has much more of a skill than the endorser, but inaccurate in that the profile holder is still nowhere near expert in that and wouldn't consider it accurate for them to claim that skill.  Is there a way to click and add just a subset (the accurate ones)?

Going down to edit the skills section and adding a new skill with the same text does not connect the endorsements with the skill listing.